# Android plus PHP special characters

Tags: php, android, special-characters

I'm currently sending info by webservice from Android to a function in PHP which sends that data to the database.

Although, if I have accents in my words like names, I receive this error from PHP:

> Incorrect string value: '\xE1\xE1mos ...' for column 'firstname' at
>   row 1

The names could have accents, like:
António, João, etc.

In PHP function, before inserting into database, I did this without success:

```
$db->set_charset('utf8');
$query = $db->prepare("SET NAMES 'utf8';"); 
$query->execute();
```

If I send the data without any kind of accents, the service works perfectly.

**Edit:** Solved using `utf8_encode(variable).`

Comment: show the insert and retrieve code.

Answer (score 2):

When sending data to your WebServices in Android, try URL encoding the strings before putting them in the URL/form data, like:

```
// ...
String encodedName = URLEncoder.encode(name, Http.UTF_8);
// use encodedName instead of name to pass as parameters to the webservices
```

In the PHP side, before using the parameter, use the urldecode function.

```
$name = urldecode ($_GET['my_param']);
```

And keep using the encoding in the database. Also, check if your tables have been created using UTF_8 colation.

Answer (score 1):

It is not enough to specify the encoding of the connection. You need to change the charset of your tables and database to utf-8.

As such, do the following

`ALTER DATABASE databasename CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;`

`ALTER TABLE tbl_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET "utf-8" COLLATE utf8_general_ci;`